# Converting string to date with to_date()

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with a `VARCHAR(64)` column called `datetimestamp` that contains datetime strings with the following format:
`[02/Jun/2016:23:58:30 +0000]`.

I'm trying to convert this to a date using `to_date(datetimestamp, 'DD/Mon/YYYY:HH24:MM:SS')` in my select statement, but I'm getting an 'Invalid Format' error.  Not sure if its the  UTC bit or what that's messing it up... what's the proper syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: it should be statement (TO_DATE('2016-06-02 23:58:30','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));

Comment: @unixmiah nope :( still get the invalid format error.

Comment: try something like this: SELECT TO_CHAR(dateColumn,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') From table;

Comment: Look at your data and your format string and see if they match.  Does `Jun` look like a day (`DD`)?

Comment: You have a semicolon in your format string

Comment: @DStanley my bad, I typed that in wrong... I was using DD/MM/YYYY.  Will correct post.  Same with the semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit complicated since `to_timestamp` does not allow time zone information.

I have come up with this query:

```
WITH d(part) AS
   (SELECT regexp_matches(
             '02/Jun/2016:23:58:30 +0000',
             '^([^ ]*) ([-+]?\d\d)(\d\d)$'
           )
   )
SELECT
   CAST (to_timestamp(d.part[1], 'DD/Mon/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
              AT TIME ZONE (d.part[2] || ':' || d.part[3])
        AS timestamp with time zone)
   AS converted
FROM d;

       converted
------------------------
 2016-06-02 21:58:30+02
(1 row)
```

(I am at time zone UTC+02.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_date('02/Jun/2016:23:58:30 +0000', 'DD/Mon/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS');

|   to_date  |
|------------|
| 2016-06-02 |
```

Comment: That will lose the time part and the time zone. You'll have to try harder.

Comment: I know but user didn't ask for them.